# Language update on background while asking upfront

Tags: android

I am pretty sure that my questions is impossible but I thought lets give it a shot.

I have a multi language app, and I change the language based on users device. However I was wondering if it is possible to ask the user first about their language preference and then load the language preferably in the background ( which seems like not possible.) I am open to suggestions.

One thing that crossed my mind was this, onStart of the firstpage I'd ask the language, save the user preference and load the content, but I am not sure if it is gonna be in the background or runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question lets take some factors into account.

**Background language changing process approach:**

1. While fetching the language data in background How will you track
   the progress that which screens language data is available and what missing?
2. What if at the middle of the language fetching process network connection     breaks?
3. While that background process was running (ongoing) what will user do
   in app?
4. For example if user was at Activity C after moving from A and B and now the language fetching process is complete and you have to set the app locale. How will you set the locale of Activity A and B who are present in Activity Stack?

I am not saying that the above discussed points are impossible to do. But for that background thing to work for us we have to devise a process to keep track of language data so that non of the required data is missing, also we have to implement retry mechanism in case of Network break and much more from a usability point of view.

**Foreground language changing process approach:**

Instead above discussed approach we can give support to the different Locales in our app by this way:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

We can also go with **another approach**:

At start of the app get the language preference from the user and then for that language data Call the Server/Backend to give you all the app language data in that api call and then Save this data to Local Database like SQLite for further use.
But with this approach you will have to work a-lot on the backed side to have a proper panel to put that language data manually and save it so that your app can query and use it again (**Note**: still this approach has its own pros and cons).

**Alot of developer will still disagree with me on these points but thats how we can think and approach to this language thing. Maybe this can help someone !**